# Is there a way to set keyboard repetition delay to zero in assembly?

Tags: assembly, input, keyboard, dos, x86-16

I'm making an assembly program that move a pixel on the screen depending of the key pressed.

According to [here](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_16-3.html) the way to modify the repetition delay is using

```
mov ah, 03h 
mov al, 05h ;set typematic rate/delay
mov bh, 00h ;repeat delay: 250ms <-- this has to be 0
mov bl, 00h ;typematic rate: 30
int 16h
```

This is the entire code

```
cmp [keypress], 'a'
je left
cmp [keypress], 'A'
je left
cmp [keypress], 'd'
je right
cmp [keypress], 'D'
je right
jmp endMove
left:
    dec xpos
    jmp endMove
right:
    inc xpos
    jmp endMove
endMove:
call drawPixel
input:
mov keypress, 0
mov ah, 01h
int 16h
jnz animLoop
mov ah, 00h
int 16h
mov keypress, al
jmp animLoop
```

It works fine except for the keyboard repetition delay that makes the pixel moving once, then stops for 250 ms and then restart moving continuously without problems.
How can i remove the repetition delay?

Comment: That's the shortest you can set. I guess you will probably need to implement your own keyboard handling instead of using BIOS.

Comment: @EuroMicelli: This question is asking about the initial delay, not the repeat period.  (Usually that's defined in terms of the rate per second, not the period = inverse rate).  Delay = 0 / rate = 50 would mean that a 1-second keypress gives exactly 50 characters, instead of 1 + 0.75 * 50 = ~38 (only 1 character during the initial 250 ms, then 50Hz).  For a game that uses key-repeat instead of tracking keys up/down itself, delay=0 would be what you want.

Comment: @PeterCordes you’re right. Deleting. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This delay (and also the repeat rate) can be configured in the BIOS options. If you want to bypass it, you shouldn't use BIOS functions but rather access the [keyboard controller](https://wiki.osdev.org/Keyboard) directly.

In your code

```
mov bh, 00h ;repeat delay: 250ms <-- this has to be 0
```

trying to set the value for the repeat delay, the value `0` stands for 250ms, the minimum that can be set in the BIOS/via the BIOS interrupt. You can verify this on [Ralph Brown's interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1757.htm).

Comment: Keyboard controller can't set smaller repeat delay than 250 ms, at least via standard PS/2 commands that all keyboards support. So it's not enough to access the keyboard controller directly. One has to implement fully custom handling of keyboard: ignore autorepeats, instead tracking keyboard state (which keys are down) and generating autorepeat events by using a custom timer.